# wordpress multisite and sucuri

Tags: wordpress, web-application-firewall, wpmu

I recently activated [Sucuri](https://sucuri.net/wordpress-security-plugin/) on a WordPress multisite with domain mapping but I am facing several issues.

First of all, the multisite is set up as subdomains with domain mapping, for example the main site is `xxxxxx.eu` and there are other subdomains in the form of:

- `en.xxxxxx.eu` mapped to `xxxxxx.com` and
- `fr.xxxxxx.eu` mapped to `xxxxxx.fr` and so on.

They all have the same IP for `A record` and the zone of the main domain also has specific `A records` for all the subdomains and a wildcard `\*.xxxxxx.eu` to the main IP (for example `111.2222.333.444`)

All mapped domains (`xxxxxx.com`, `xxxxxx.fr`, etc.) have switched their `A records` to `Sucuri` to different IPs: `123.234.345.456`, or `123.234.345.457`, etc., except the main one `xxxxxx.eu` which still points to the original web hosting `111.222.333.444`

So now here are the issues. When I tried to put the main domain `xxxxxx.eu` to the firewall on it's own IP, I also added all the subdomains to that IP (`en.xxxxxx.eu`, `fr.xxxxxx.eu`) and so I had issues with the images being displayed on websites because on the website `xxxxxx.com` the images are referenced as `en.xxxxxx.eu`.

So I removed it and now I have only the mapped domains.

However I also have a very strange issue. Sometimes and for only one minute, when someone tries to visit `xxxxxx.com` they are being sent to the `xxxxxx.eu/wp-signup.php?new=xxxxxxxxx.com` sign up page.

This happen only for a minute at most and the strange thing is that it is happening on desktop and (at least to my knowledge) only inside our office network.

So my questions are, any ideas how to properly set this WP MU in `Sucuri`? Any ideas what this sign-up page is all about? It started only after I activated the firewall on `xxxxxxxx.com`.

For now I have still some domains outside the firewall because I cannot afford having this sign-up page appear once or twice per day.

Comment: Securi is a commercial product with a support team, FWIW.

Comment: Hi, yes i know that Sucuri is a commercial product, however their responce to my ticket does not look like one

**Thank you for your patience in this matter,

We have limited support we can offer for WordPress multisite network configuration. We recommend reporting any questions or issues to the support forum so an expert can assist**